# Using ADB command know the name of application focussed using adb

Tags: android, adb

I am using the

> adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT

to focus on an application, now i want to know the name of the application on which this has focussed using adb shell command.

NOTE: not exactly the name of application, it can focus on anything. SO i want to get the Text on which it focusses.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/q/26586685/1778421 to find out which specific view has the focus

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

> adb shell uiautomator dump /dev/tty

You will get an XML describing the current screen, one of the many `<node>-elements` will have an attribute `focused="true"`. It may also have a `text-attribute` and a lot more UI-informations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. To do it, you need to use grep terminal application on your phone (the easiest way with rooted phone with busybox package). Let do the same steps as below:

```
C:\Users\Hasan>adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT

C:\Users\Hasan>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
su
root@android:/ # dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
  mCurrentFocus=Window{42079c60 com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro/com.jrummy.apps.rom.toolbox.RomToolboxActivity paused=false}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{4283d918 token=Token{426709a8 ActivityRecord{41e37c60 com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro/com.jrummy.apps.rom.toolbox.RomToolboxActivity}}}
root@android:/ #
```

Now you'll see which activity has focus :)

Comment: If device is unrooted is there any way

Comment: Of course, just use first part of instruction:
dumpsys window windows
and then in your app/script grep answer from terminal (you can use any regular expression to find these lines).

Comment: Its not giving the corret app in focus

Comment: It is impossible, this command always show you which app has focus. Show me your results.