# Is there a way to get current activity's layout and views via adb?

Tags: android, adb, android-view, android-uiautomator

For environment reasons I can only use **`adb`** commands.

**Is there a way** to get the current layout attributes like `id`, `position`, `text` etc **?**

Similar to what **`uiautomatorviewer`** shows.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use `adb shell uiautomator dump` command:

```
Usage: uiautomator <subcommand> [options]

Available subcommands:

help: displays help message

runtest: executes UI automation tests
    runtest <class spec> [options]
    <class spec>: <JARS> < -c <CLASSES> | -e class <CLASSES> >
      <JARS>: a list of jar files containing test classes and dependencies. If
        the path is relative, it's assumed to be under /data/local/tmp. Use
        absolute path if the file is elsewhere. Multiple files can be
        specified, separated by space.
      <CLASSES>: a list of test class names to run, separated by comma. To
        a single method, use TestClass#testMethod format. The -e or -c option
        may be repeated. This option is not required and if not provided then
        all the tests in provided jars will be run automatically.
    options:
      --nohup: trap SIG_HUP, so test won't terminate even if parent process
               is terminated, e.g. USB is disconnected.
      -e debug [true|false]: wait for debugger to connect before starting.
      -e runner [CLASS]: use specified test runner class instead. If
        unspecified, framework default runner will be used.
      -e <NAME> <VALUE>: other name-value pairs to be passed to test classes.
        May be repeated.
      -e outputFormat simple | -s: enabled less verbose JUnit style output.

dump: creates an XML dump of current UI hierarchy
    dump [--verbose][file]
      [--compressed]: dumps compressed layout information.
      [file]: the location where the dumped XML should be stored, default is
      /storage/emulated/legacy/window_dump.xml

events: prints out accessibility events until terminated
```

By default it dumps the views hierarchy to `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/window_dump.xml`

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
UI hierchary dumped to: /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

Usually you would want to pull that file to your PC for further processing which would be an extra step. But there is a neat trick which allows to combine dumping and pulling into a single command. Using `/dev/tty` as a dump destination would make a single command which would print the whole dump to the `stdout`:

```
adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><hierarchy rotation="0"><node ...></node></hierarchy>UI hierchary dumped to: /dev/tty
```

Comment: Wanted to add a note that only one UIAutomator client can be running or the command will output "killed" and not work. I was stumped by this until I found out I was blocked by running tests using an open UIAutomator connection.

Comment: @Alex I tried running the command ui automator dump to get the ui hierarchy from android emulator, but it seems that I am not getting the complete dump. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to get the dump for the activity of UCBrowser running in android emulator so that I can get the bound of a button/item to click. I have also asked a question on SO regarding same here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780490/automate-the-installation-of-ucbrowser

Comment: I got this error :( `null root node returned by UiTestAutomationBridge`

Answer (score 8):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s `dump` tool lets you do precisely that. AndroidViewClient can be used as a library and also provides some tools like `dump` and `culebra`.

```
usage: dump [OPTION]... [serialno]

Options:
  -H, --help                       prints this help                             
  -V, --verbose                    verbose comments                             
  -v, --version
  -I, --ignore-secure-device       ignore secure device                         
  -E, --ignore-version-check       ignores ADB version check                    
  -F, --force-view-server-use      force view server use (even if UiAutomator present:w)
  -S, --do-not-start-view-server   don't start ViewServer                       
  -k, --do-not-ignore-uiautomator-killed don't ignore UiAutomator killed              
  -w, --window=WINDOW              dump WINDOW content (default: -1, all windows)
  -a, --all                        dump all information about Views             
  -i, --uniqueId                   dump View unique IDs                         
  -x, --position                   dump View positions                          
  -b, --bounds                     dump View bounds                             
  -d, --content-description        dump View content descriptions               
  -g, --tag                        dump View tags                               
  -c, --center                     dump View centers                            
  -f, --save-screenshot=FILE       save screenshot to file                      
  -W, --save-view-screenshots=DIR  save View screenshots to files in directory  
  -D, --do-not-dump-views          don't dump views, only useful if you specified -f or -W
  -A, --device-art=MODEL           device art model to frame screenshot (auto: autodetected)
  -Z, --drop-shadow                drop shadow for device art screenshot        
  -B, --glare                      screen glare over screenshot                 
  -h, --use-uiautomator-helper     use UiAutomatorHelper Android app            
  -X, --debug=LIST                 debug options
```

running `dump` with no options, just prints the tree of Views and some of its basic properties, like ID

```
android.widget.FrameLayout  
   com.android.launcher3.Workspace com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/workspace 
      android.widget.FrameLayout com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/workspace_blocked_row 
         android.widget.TextView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/date_text1 May 1
         android.widget.TextView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/date_text2 MONDAY, 2017
      android.widget.TextView  Maps
   android.widget.ImageView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/g_icon 
   android.widget.ImageView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/all_apps_handle 
   android.view.ViewGroup com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/layout 
      android.widget.TextView  Messenger
      android.widget.TextView  Chrome
```

on the other hand, if you want the positions of the views, you can run

$ dump -x

```
android.widget.FrameLayout   (0, 0, 1440, 2392)
   com.android.launcher3.Workspace com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/workspace  (0, 0, 1440, 2392)
      android.widget.FrameLayout com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/workspace_blocked_row  (30, 126, 1380, 372)
         android.widget.TextView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/date_text1 May 1 (1037, 194, 337, 162)
         android.widget.TextView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/date_text2 MONDAY, 2017 (1092, 356, 282, 73)
      android.widget.TextView  Maps (30, 1614, 276, 372)
   android.widget.ImageView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/g_icon  (30, 214, 276, 196)
   android.widget.ImageView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/all_apps_handle  (636, 1986, 168, 98)
   android.view.ViewGroup com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/layout  (0, 2084, 1440, 308)
      android.widget.TextView  Messenger (306, 2112, 276, 280)
      android.widget.TextView  Chrome (858, 2112, 276, 280)
```

The options will give you control over the output. You can get some more info [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/dump).

#### update 2022

A newer backend is available for **AndroidViewClient/culebra** and one of the newer features is that you can also obtain the View hierarchy dump in **JSON** instead of **XML**.

For example:

```
$ dump -ah emulator-5554 | jq
⚠️ CulebraTester2 server should have been started and port redirected.
{
  "id": "hierarchy",
  "text": "Window Hierarchy",
  "timestamp": "2020-10-12T02:18:45.639Z",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "parent": -1,
      "text": "",
      "package": "com.android.systemui",
      "checkable": false,
      "clickable": false,
      "index": 0,
      "content_description": "",
      "focusable": false,
    ...
```

more details at [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public).

Answer (score 6):

```
adb pull $(adb shell uiautomator dump | grep -oP '[^ ]+.xml') /tmp/view.xml
```

Open `/tmp/view.xml` in a web browser like:

```
google-chrome /tmp/view.xml
```

> adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty

from the other answer didn't work for me.

Comment: in my computer not work. i change to this  `adb pull $(adb shell uiautomator dump | egrep -o '/.*?xml')`

Answer (score 5):

Use the following to view the xml layout in notepad or your default text editor

```
adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml && start window_dump.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the following on a Mac to print formatted xml to the console:

`adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml $TMPDIR && more $TMPDIR/window_dump.xml | xmllint --format -`

You may need to change the path of the `/sdcard/window_dump.xml` file to pull based on where the xml file is dumped.

Comment: does it work even within the OS itself, using root ? Also, is there a way to just print it, instead of using a file?

Answer (score 1):

`adb shell uiautomator dump /dev/stdout` works better for me than `adb shell uiautomator dump /dev/tty`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to control the resource with calculated position using by UIAutomator.

- How to get the information about current layout information.
  adb exec-out "uiautomator dump /dev/tty > /dev/null
- How to calculate the XY coordinates
  From the output acquired on above.
  We can find the bounds information of target control with resource-id.
  the bounds information is bounds="[334,1789][505,1960]" if the resource-id is "com.samsung.android.dialer:id/dialButton".

```html
    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.samsung.android.dialer
:id/dialButton" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.samsung.android.dialer" content-desc="Call button" check
able="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-cl
ickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[334,1789][505,1960]">
```

- bounds value in the node
  Top-Left : [334,1789], Bottom-Right : [505, 1960]

we can get the center position of control("com.samsung.android.dialer
:id/dialButton") from the bounds values.

X = 334 + round{(505-334 + 1) / 2} => 420
Y = 1789 + round{(1960 – 1789 + 1) / 2} => 1875

We can check the bound of target control and it can be used for remote control of target resource.

adb shell input tap 420 1875

For more information, I hope following link is helpful for your question.

https://lowellahn.tistory.com/m/1

Comment: First off welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by `resource` and `calculated position`. Please provide more info than a URL (which may become broken at any time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -7):

In 2020 it's recommended to use a tool built-in Android Studio.

1. Connect your phone
2. Follow the screenshot

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

[image]

Comment: In 2020 it's recommended to read the question you are replying to. *For environment reasons I can only use `adb` commands.*