# Where to see the xml file after "adb shell uiautomator dump view.xml"

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I use command

```
adb shell uiautomator dump view.xml
```

to dump the UI hierarchy of current Android screen. Then, I try to see the **view.xml**, I tried command:

```
adb shell cat view.xml
```

but get error:

```
/system/bin/sh: cat: view.xml: No such file or directory
```

How/Where can I see the dumped view.xml file?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do the following:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump  

adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

If you directly want to read out from shell  you can execute following command from adb shell after dumping the XML

```
adb shell cat /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Being on your developer machine you can dump the "UI hierarchy of current Android screen" to `/sdcard/window_dump.xml` on the smartphone with command:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
```

the response is:

```
UI hierchary dumped to: /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

then you can `cat` the xml to your developer machine's filesystem with command:

```
adb shell cat /sdcard/window_dump.xml > ~/duuuuuuuuuuuump.xml
```

the you can view it with favorite xml viewer, for example `nano`:

```
nano ~/duuuuuuuuuuuump1.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use absolute path or just use `adb shell uiautomator dump` without filename parameter at all - it will use the default location. In your case you are trying to create the `/view.xml` file and you have no writing permission for the `/` folder.

Comment: But I also tried `adb shell uiautomator dump /tmp/view.xml`, then I run `adb shell` and go to `cd tmp/`, when I `ls`,  it is empty there too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26586685/1778421