# Does starting the adb shell take a lot of resources?

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I use a bash script to automate processes on Android devices in my office. I call the shell like this in the script: (Let the `...` stand for any amount of adb shell commands.)

```
#!/bin/bash

...

adb shell do stuff
adb shell do stuff
adb shell do stuff

...

exit
```

These scripts function very well. I have already done research on sending multiple commands to a single instance of shell; I'm wondering if they are as efficient as they can be though. Am I using a lot of system resources? Could this potentially raise issues in the future when I'll be running very very large automation scripts using this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting of the new `sh` process does not take a lot of time or resources. Queuing multiple commands to the same `sh` instance does not provide any noticeable performance improvement. Just be mindful of what commands you run in those `shell` sessions. Some commands like `input` are not native binaries but `java` applications which take longer time to start - so do not expect to be able to fire multiples of those per second.

Comment: This actually explains a lot. This question is related to a scenario in my other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278510/adb-shell-input-command-changes-when-ran-on-multiple-devices/39282793

Slowing down my `input` commands allowed those commands to fire through accurately. Pretty interesting that the `input` commands are java apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big deal, but you can do

```
adb shell <<!
    do stuff
    do stuff
    do stuff
!
```

which is sometimes useful if you have some `if`s or loops as it's much easier to write and visualize.

Comment: *which is sometimes useful* but still **does not provide any noticeable performance improvement**

Comment: Perhaps it does: `time for n in {0..9999}; do  adb shell ls -l ">" /dev/null; done

real 3m29.764s
user 0m1.032s
sys 0m1.560s
$ time while [ $i -lt 10000 ]
> do 
> ls -l > /dev/null
> i=$(( i + 1 ))
> done
    2m1.52s real     0m2.43s user     0m5.68s system`