# Can adb command be used to check/change focus on a view?

Tags: android, focus, adb

adb can be used for various operations on views, touches, key-strokes, etc...

Can it also check or change the focus of views?

For example, if there are a lot of views on the current activity, and I'd like to scroll on a listView, I could choose the listView to be focused by providing its id, and it will get a focus so that I could emulate page-down key. Alternatively, I could emulate tab-key till I see that the currently focused view is a listView.

Comment: never used it, but if `ACTION_CLICK` performs "click" then try `AccessibilityNodeInfo#ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD` or in general `ACTION_FOCUS`

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Given an id of a view, how would I set it to work with what you wrote?

Comment: i already gave you a service that "clicks" on any view using `ACTION_CLICK` just change the action to some other

Comment: I asked about adb, but what exactly is your solution? Please show in an answer and not a comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315028/is-it-possible-to-use-adb-commands-to-click-on-a-view-by-finding-its-id#comment66085074_39315028

Comment: @pskink This is about focusing on a view. Not clicking it. As an example, as I've written, if I have a listView, I'd like to know how to focus on it, and scroll in it using page-down key. Besides, what you've shown there doesn't have a solution in any of the answers, using what you wrote here.

Comment: so change the ACTION, dont use ACTION_CLICK but one i posted in me first comment here

Comment: Again, I asked about adb. Not a service. But it could be interesting too, so if you wish to answer using a service, please write as an answer.

Comment: so you will use adb,  `adb shell ...`

Comment: Yes, and the "..." - what would it be?

Comment: either "am startservice ..." or "dumpsys activity service ..."

Comment: What service? I told you. I don't use a service, but if you have a solution with a service, please write it down, because it might be useful

Comment: then read this comment again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315028/is-it-possible-to-use-adb-commands-to-click-on-a-view-by-finding-its-id#comment66085074_39315028 and ^F `can be done by this service`

Comment: @pskink Again, this question is about adb command, but if you have another possible solution, please write it down as an answer, and not as a comment.

Comment: again, `adb` is used, when you execute `adb shell am startservice ...` in ytour opinion is `adb` command used or not?

Comment: @pskink if "..." is the service I need to create, then it's not adb alone. Plus, you didn't show how to use it, especially not here.

Comment: because i dont want to repeat the same thing twice, you dont want a custom `AccessibilityService`? its ok, wait for anyone else answer (i dont think you will receive any response though...)

Comment: @pskink You never did write an answer on the thread you've linked to, so it's not twice.

Comment: you have a full source code of a working service, just integrate it with your app, what more do you expect?

Comment: @pskink I don't see any answer of a full source code of a working service. Not here and not there.

Comment: because there is no answer,  but you have full source code of a working service which you have to add to your app and modify your manifest file

Comment: If there is no answer, what did you write all this time about? I don't have any source code of a service.

Comment: i posted the link to a comment which points to a service code, i posted it twice here, did you even try to open it? am i to post it the 3rd time?

Comment: You wrote there is no answer, which is correct: Not here, and not there. There is no full code of an answer. Not even a part of it.

Comment: so you did not find a link i posted here twice?

Comment: Since I already wrote about it, it should be known that I did see it, and as we both wrote, it's not an answer because it's not written in an answer and since it doesn't include the solution to the current question.

Comment: that link points to a comment to one of another question, right? and this comment contains a link to a **full** source code of a  **working** service which you are supposed to add to your app

Comment: Again, I asked about adb command, without any service. I wrote you that if you have another solution without it, please post it here as an answer. The link you've provided doesn't contain any answer to the current question (and it's not even an answer to the question I've posted there), and I don't know how to use it. Please, if you do have a solution, write about it.

Comment: so did you see that service code or not? then simply change `ACTION_CLICK` to `ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD` or `ACTION_FOCUS`, it is so simple that i will not post the modified code if it requires replacing ONE constant with another, OK in case if you say there is no full sources code then this is the code i'm talking about: http://pastebin.com/kH01PqYs

Comment: Which of those returns me the id of the focused view?

Answer (score 6):

You can figure out what view is focused by dumping the view hierarchy and scanning the output:

```
# dump and extract
adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml

# prettify if you want
xmllint --format window_dump.xml > window_dump.pretty.xml

# then grep
cat window_dump.pretty.xml | grep focused=\"true\"

<node index="2" text="" resource-id="YOUR_PACKAGE:id/resize_button" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="YOUR_PACKAGE" content-desc="Enter dominant view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[180,60][252,132]">
```

Comment: Any way to do it using root, on the Android app itself? And do you know how to focus on specific view too?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for a way to scroll through the views by pressing TAB, the following should do it

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_TAB
```

If someone arrives here looking for a way to change focus on different activities (not views) via ADB

We can get the current focused window/app using

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E "mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp"
```

In order to set focus, we need a 2 step process 1) get the task ID to focus 2) focus on it

```
# get the task ID, it is the number after # in the output
adb shell dumpsys activity recents | grep "#"
# set focus
adb shell am task focus <task ID>
```

Comment: Interesting. And what about focusing on a specific View in the app?

Comment: I am not aware of a clean way to do this. Did you find a way. If yes, please feel free to post it here for the dev community to benefit!

Comment: No idea how to do it.