# Android: How to capture the text on screen from any app or through adb?

Tags: android, testing, adb, accessibility

Is it possible to capture the text that is rendered on screen from any app using an app or adb, for the purposes of automated testing, or accessibility?

My only alternative is to take a screenshot and run it through an OCR application.

Comment: Do you control the application that is printing the text?  If no, what kind of text are you trying to get, generated by what application, etc?

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/q/26586685/1778421 would work for you

Comment: @AlexP. that looks like it does work, but looks like it applies to your own apps, or to all apps?

Comment: @jconder I don't control the application. Let's say I want to get to the folder name in Gmail, such as 'Inbox'.

Comment: It works for all normal apps (ones using regular widgets with accessibility support). The apps do not have to be the debug versions

Answer (score 3):

> for the purposes of automated testing

If this is your UI, write instrumentation tests using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html), which has result matchers for checking the text of `TextView` and its subclasses.

If this is not your UI, and you are performing integration testing, write instrumentation tests using [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html), which has some ability to get text from `TextView` and its subclasses.

> for the purposes of... accessibility

[Write an `AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html).

Comment: I've clarified better in my question that this should work for any app. So the second half of your answer is perfect.