# auto press button with unknown coordinates in android

Tags: android, python, shell, adb

Good day!
I am looking for an opportunity to imitate button pressing on android devices.
We can make it with adb:
adb shell input tap x y

But what can I do if I don't know this coordinates?
I know that we can touch this button before and get coordinates but it's not suitable for me... Do you know how to get field for typing coordinates automatically without human touching?

Thank you for regards!

Comment: You probably need a more complex tool like [uiautomator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26586685/1778421