# get the uiautomator dump in a file and then parse it to get the bounds

Tags: android, xml, linq, android-uiautomator

I am working on getting the layout view of an activity and then parsing to get the bound of the required item.
I am using uiautomator view to get the layout view using `"adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty"` but I want it to get into a file so that I can use it for parsing using Linq to XML

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(output);
```

I have gone through answer at [Is there a way to get current activity's layout and views via adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586685/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-activitys-layout-and-views-via-adb) but not getting much help.Please suggest some pointer over it.

Comment: i think there is no way at present moment instead of parsing

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s `dump` tool lets you do precisely that and many, many more stuff

```
$ dump -b
```

gives you the View bounds, something like

```
android.widget.FrameLayout   ((0, 0), (1080, 2048))
   android.widget.TextView com.example.app:id/text Something ((64, 64), (221, 123))
   ...
```

More details [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/dump).

Comment: I don't think that I can use any other library and bound to use adb.exe.
Also what if we don't have any particular ids for the item/button we want to click.
It will be good if we can get the output in an xml and then parse it according to our use.
adb exec-out uiautomator dump  - it gives the output in a xml way but only issue is that I am not able to save it to a string/file which I can load in XDocument.Load(output).

Comment: for the cases when you don't have IDs (or IDs are repeated) AndroidViewClient always assign a *unique ID* to all views. Don't understand what you mean by `bound`, but AVC uses `adbclient` which connects to `adb`.

Comment: Due to some environment constraint, I can't use other than adb.exe. I mean I can't install AndroidViewClient . By bounds I meant this value of the coordinates within which an item/button exist - for ex:  ((64, 64), (221, 123))

Comment: Well, if you want to do it yourself, take a look at AVC's source code and see how it gets the dump for different API levels. That's the beauty of Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:
adb shell uiautomator dump /storage/sdcard/uiAuto.xml

This puts the dump in a file 'uiAuto.xml'. You can now pull this to a local file and then read it.

To pull it use:
adb pull /storage/sdcard/uiAuto.xml [anylocalfile]