# Is there any other way to find the elements in appium other than automatarviewer

Tags: android, appium, nativeapplication

My app doesn't have debug mode enabled, so I have only one way to identify the elements i.e., automaterviewer, when I am trying to find an element in the screen with it, it throws error, unable to take the screenshot :EOF.

So please let me know if there is any other way to find the elements for the Native Android mobile app

[Error thrown in Automaterviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si1rD.png)

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586685/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-activitys-layout-and-views-via-adb

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what debug mode on an app means. Also, UIAutomatorViewer doesn't depend on the app in any way. It just shows whatever is displayed on your screen. It can be any app or even the lock screen as well. It mostly might be a device issue. Try with a different phone and see if the issue persists.

Also, you can use Appium desktop as well to inspect the elements. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Anish, I am able to get the DOM for all the screens except the one screen, so clearly its not an Device issue.

I have installed Appium Desktop (1.6.5) and I don't see any option to inspect, could you please help me in this.